# ssh: execute privileged command when a non-root user logs in?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, sshd

I am trying to run a command/script that requires root privileges when a non-root user logs into ssh

This unfortunately means I cannot use   `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc`

I also tried `/etc/ssh/sshrc` but it has the same problem, the command executes as the logged in user.

I see `/etc/profile.d/` does something but not sure how to use it or if it will have the same problem.

sshd does run as root so I am hoping it can be taught to do this somehow

I do need to know the ip of the login for the command.

Thanks for any ideas!

added: sudo is not possible because it's for a non-privileged user without sudo rights

Comment: Please include the actual command you need to run (answers will be different for scripts and compiled binaries for example).

Comment: Setuo sudo.  Use `sudo ...` where required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pam_exec` as a PAM session module.

Comment: Oh wow, I never knew about PAM. Reading up now, looks very promising. Any ideas how to grab the remote ip since it doesn't look like it's included in the PAM environment?

Comment: @ck_: It's in the PAM_RHOST ['PAM item'](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_get_item), but pam_exec exports it as an environment variable (`$PAM_RHOST`) as well.