# Execute a script as root when non root user logs in

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sudo, root

I've seen this question asked before [here](https://superuser.com/questions/619595/execute-a-script-as-root-on-every-ssh-login) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/617102/ssh-execute-privileged-command-when-a-non-root-user-logs-in) but they're pretty old and I haven't been able to get any solution to work.

Basically I need to run a script or command automatically as root each time a non root user SSH's into the server.  Server is running Ubuntu 16.04 and using OpenSSH if that makes a difference.

EDIT:
To be more specific, I want to kill a process that was created by user A when user B logs in.  My roommates and I mine crypto on my headless gaming server and I'd like to be able to run `pkill miner.sh` automatically when someone logs in, regardless of who started it.  Since it would be insanely insecure to let users kill each others' processes, it seems that this is more difficult than expected.

Comment: `pam_exec` mentioned in the second question is also what I'd try. Needs a bit of reading up on PAM.

Comment: @dirkt Yea I saw that but I got permission errors when I tried it.  I'll look more into it I really don't know PAM so that could be the issue

Comment: You may get a better answer if you explain what you actually want done at login (there may be a better way than executing a script as root).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding all users to a group called mygroup

```
sudo groupadd mygroup
sudo usermod -aG mygroup user1
sudo usermod -aG mygroup user2
```

Then modifying `/etc/sudoers` to allow this group to execute `sudo pkill` without a password by adding the following to sudoers

`%mygroup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pkill`

Then I just added the command `sudo pkill` to the bottom of `/etc/profile` and it worked a charm.

Answer (score 2):

pam_exec has you pointed in the right direction, but setuid is bad advice; most (all?) modern Linuxes ignore it on shell scripts and only respect it on binary executable files.

Would it be a problem if the script was executed (as root) at times other than login?
If it's ok for it to run more often than strictly required, you could create a wrapper script that's executed at every ssh login with user permissions which uses sudo (with no password) to execute your script as root.
This, however, means that the users could also run it manually (as root) as often as they wanted to.

To set this up, add this line to /etc/pam.d/sshd

`account optional        pam_exec.so     /etc/pam.d/LoginWrapper.sh`

Then create the file /etc/pam.d/LoginWrapper.sh with contents:

`#!/bin/bash
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then # Execute only when a user other than root logs in
   /usr/bin/sudo /path/to/your/root_script.sh
fi`

Note that if your sudo is in a different path, you should update it above.

Now in /etc/sudoers add the line:

`ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/root_script.sh`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Omnipresence but I still get `pkill: killing pid 2629 failed: Operation not permitted` when I try to run it.  My root_script.sh is basically just `pkill miner.sh`

Comment: I updated my question with more info, I'm not really set on doing this any particular way, its just a simple thing that I wanted to do for convenience that has caused me to dig a lot deeper into Linux user permissions.  At this point I want to do it just to prove it can be done!